# Uploading image in 000webhost don't work using laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel, image, upload, hosting

I'm working on a Laravel project, and I make a feature that the user can upload image for its profile, and I use the public path to save the avatars cause 000webhost doesn't support (storage:link) and every thing works better in local 
but when I upload the project on 000webhost, it refuses to upload the image and returns error (The image failed to upload.)
How can i solve it

**config/filesystem.php**

```
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('storage2'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage2',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

**controller**

```
public function Change(Request $request)
    {
        $Validate = $this->Validation($request);
        if (!$Validate->fails()) {
            $User = $this->getUser();

            $OldImage = $User->image;

            $Extension = $request->file("image")->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $NewImage = str_random(30) . "." . $Extension;
            Storage::putFileAs($this->privatePath, $request->file("image"), $NewImage);

            $User->update(["image" => $NewImage]);

            Storage::delete($this->privatePath ."/". $OldImage);

            session()->flash("message", "You have changed your image");
            return back();
        } else {
            session()->flash("error", $Validate->errors()->first());
            return back();
        }
    }
```

But the problem is not in the code, cause it works in local 
I think the problem with some permissions or in file .htaccess or anything like that

Comment: Welcome in Stackoverflow. We’d love to help you. 
To get a good Answer for your Question: Can you edit the question and provide 
some code and/or more explanations, if there is, of what 
you are doing, and what's wrong. To avoid downvote and bad comments, 
please take some time to read [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help)
 and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)